# gghighlight creating extra points

Tags: r, ggplot2, gghighlight

gghighlight seems to be creating extra points when I highlight. Any tips here? I imagine I must be doing something wrong.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gghighlight)
mtcars<-mtcars

#produces as expected
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x=factor(cyl),y=wt,col=factor(gear)),show.legend = FALSE)
#produces as expected

#creates extra points?
ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x=factor(cyl),y=wt,col=factor(gear)),show.legend = FALSE)+gghighlight::gghighlight(wt>3,label_key = gear)
```

Edit, adding plots:

[image: First plot, which is working]

[image]

Comment: Both codes work fine, what do you mean by extra points?

Comment: @Duck It seems like new point appear with the highlight. For instance: theres 3 points w/ wt>5 and cyl==8 (visible in the first line). Once the highlight is added, there seems to be new unhighlighted points around those original 3 points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does indeed seem to be the case:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gghighlight)

mtcars <- mtcars

#using geom_point insted of geom_jitter since geom_jitter adds noise to the points, thus making plots tougher to reproduce and compare:

#no highlight:
ggplot()+
  geom_point(mtcars, mapping = aes(x = factor(cyl),y = wt,col = factor(gear)), show.legend = FALSE,, position=position_dodge(width = 0.5))

#with highlight:
ggplot()+
  geom_point(mtcars, mapping = aes(x = factor(cyl),y = wt,col = factor(gear)), show.legend = FALSE, position=position_dodge(width = 0.5))+
  gghighlight(wt > 3,label_key = gear)
```

[image]
see grey points for cyl=6 to the left of the red points labelled with a "3".
[image]

```
#new points seem to appear for cyl=6 (grey ones to the left), so lets look at these specifically:
#first: how many values should be there?
only_cyl_6 <- subset(mtcars, mtcars$cyl==6)
length(only_cyl_6$wt)
#7 
#but we see 6 points in our first plot. A quick look @ only_cyl_6 reveals that #two values have the same wt value:
only_cyl_6
# -> Merc 280 & Merc 280C      
#so the first plot seems to be fine...geom_jitter supports this.

ggplot()+
  geom_jitter(only_cyl_6, mapping = aes(x = factor(cyl),y = wt,col = factor(gear)), show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

```
#now we see 7 point. thats good.

#lets add highlight again:

ggplot()+
  geom_jitter(only_cyl_6, mapping = aes(x = factor(cyl),y = wt,col = factor(gear)), show.legend = FALSE)+
  gghighlight(wt > 3,label_key = gear)
```

[image]

Now there are 9.
So in conclusion: adding highlight does indeed seem to make additional points being plotted...

Comment: thanks for the help on this. Your example works well except I seem to see 9 points. I'm starting to think it's creating new points to highlight and the jitter leaves the old points visible (normally would be covered).

Comment: Your absolutely right. There are indeed 9 points with highlight. Seems like I cant count. Edited my Answer accordingly and added pictures illustrating the issue. Sorry.